# FlexSlider Auto Height still leaving a space below slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, flexslider

I have auto height on my flexslider and its still leaving a space below it.

I have applied a background colour to the slider and it is using auto height and moving up and down but it seems like the slider is taking the biggest photo and keeping the slider at that height.

Any help would be great!

You can see the page live here: http://therichmondhillgallery.com/index.php/shows/bruce-yardley/

```
This is my html:
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li class="slide">
<img src="<?php echo $thumb_image; ?>" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide">
       <img class="slidermainimg" src="<?php echo $main_image; ?>" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
/* Browser Resets
*********************************/
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

/* Icon Fonts
*********************************/
/* Font-face Icons */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
    src:url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; margin-right:10px;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "\0020"; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;}
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.flexslider { margin: 0 0 30px; position: relative; zoom: 1; }
.flex-viewport { max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; -o-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease; }
.loading .flex-viewport { max-height: 300px; }
.flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; }
.carousel li { margin-right: 5px;}

/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a  { text-decoration:none; display: block; width: 40px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; position: absolute; top: 55%; z-index: 10; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.6; cursor: pointer; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3); -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; -moz-transition: all .3s ease; transition: all .3s ease; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: 10px; display: block;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: 10px; text-align: right; display: block;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 1; left: 10px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 1; right: 10px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover { opacity: 1; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled { opacity: 0!important; filter:alpha(opacity=0); cursor: default; }
.flex-direction-nav a:before  { font-family: "flexslider-icon"; font-size: 30px; display: inline-block; content: '\f001'; color:#ffffff; }
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before  { content: '\f002'; }

/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -40px; text-align: center;}
.flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.flex-control-paging li a {width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
.flex-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); cursor: default; }

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

#slider {background-color:#ff6600; margin-bottom:0px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { opacity: 1; left: 10px;}
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { opacity: 1; right: 10px;}
}
```

And this is my javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
              $('#carousel').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: true,
            itemWidth: 200,
            itemMargin: 10,
            minItems: 5,
            move: 5,
            controlNav: false,
                asNavFor: '#slider'
              });

              $('#slider').flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: true,
                slideshow: false,
                smoothHeight: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 20000,
            directionNav: false,
                sync: "#carousel"
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: In [Chrome Dev Tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) it's giving an error on the flexslider.css (file not found) try making sure its path is correct and perhaps that might fix it?

Comment: Hi Victor I have looked into that, That is just a line of code I forgot to take out when converting the site to a Wordpress theme, I have removed it and its still the same... It does seem to auto height when the page first loads but then it pops back to the height of the tallest image..

Comment: If you add `overflow: hidden` to`#slider` its fixes it but you shouldn't need to do that. I'd personally re-install the slider plugin.

Comment: Added as an answer - could you accept, ta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
overflow: hidden
```

to

```
#slider
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solve an issue that I have with flexslider with thumbsnail down to slider to select a photo that you want to see "on big". When I inserted a vertical image, flexslider left a white space down very ugly because of vertical photo..... thank you again ;)

Comment: I added overflow:hidden to ul.slides 
It worked for me!!