# flex-slider first slide has wrong height on mobile

Tags: drupal-7, flexslider

I have enabled smooth height on flex-slider but the content on the first slide gets cropped as on [this image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBX3E.png). I checked with code inspector and noticed it gets the wrong height. When I navigate to the next slide and back to the first, it now gets the correct height. Where might be the problem?

[Correct image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uqVF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to Drupal, you have a css/js issue.
A quick search returns some issues similar to yours:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125105/flexslider-cant-adjust-height

[FlexSlider Auto Height still leaving a space below slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301261/flexslider-auto-height-still-leaving-a-space-below-slider)

Before asking for help, you should at least provide some code and the solutions you already tested and did not work.